# Help with the chain rule $h(t)=f(t, X(t))$

Tags: calculus

Assume we have the function $h(t)=f(t, X(t)): \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. How to I calculate $h'$?

I thought of letting $g:t \rightarrow(t,X(t))$ and then  $h' = g'(t)f'(g(t)) = (1, X_{t})f'(t,X(t))$ but it is not a scalar... so where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you did not understand the chain rule. Since you are working with functions of several variables, the order in which you "multiply" the derivatives *matters*. Since $h = f \circ g$, you should "multiply" $f'(t,X(y))(1,X'(t))$, where $f'$ is the *Jacobian matrix* of $f$. More explicitly,
$$
h'(t) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial X}X'(t).
$$

Answer (score 0):

If $X(t) = x(t)$ then $h(t) = f(t,x(t))$ and
$$
  \frac{df}{dt} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} 
 + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}
$$
Can you proceed from here?